# window.open does not work as expected, need some advice

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm new on JavaScript.
I have a function that does not working as I expected.
I have some input text (multiple, similar). I added an id for each.

I used JavaScript function to get the value, then transfer them to another page to be processed. But my function script gone wrong, I need a solution, please help.

This script keeps open a new tab. All I want is to open to its window, that currently on a frame named 'main'.

This is my function :

```
function addFrame(fid){  
    var xfra= "x"+fid;  
    var nfr= document.getElementById(xfra).value;  
    var nwo= fid;  
    var link= "http://127.0.0.1/nims/index.php/jpbgr/frame/18?
    xid=18&menu=new&order="+nwo+"&frame="+nfr;  
    var Util= window.open(link);   
}
```

Even if I changed to:

`var Util= window.open(link, "main");`

But still not working.

I used CodeIgniter.

Thank you.

=======
this is the index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IMS-2017</title>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="0,*" frameborder=0 noresize>
    <frame src="dummy.php" name="top" frameborder=0 noresize>
    <frame src="./../nims/index.php/jpbgr/proses/18?xid=18&jid=CR" name="main">
  </frameset>
</html>
```

this the form inside the body tag:

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Frame Number" id="x1015909">
<button onclick="addFrame('1015909');">GO</button>
</form>
```

i want this function sends the text inputted to other page, but still in the same window. my first try is to use window.open() but i guess i'm wrong.

any idea how to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your problem seems unclear. You have an iframe, and you want to load that into the iframe? If yes, could you also add that code piece?

Comment: Take some time to read through [ask]. Need a more detailed description of the problem, what it does or doesn't do, errors it produces etc. Also take time to read [mcve]

Comment: *This script keeps open a new tab.* thats what window.open does.May have a look at window.location="http://test";

Comment: Extrasense is here. Your browser prevent popups from JS. Please check browser address bar in the top right angle and allows popups.

Comment: thank you everyone. i added some 'completion' to my question, after ====.  sorry, my englih is very bad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be using [encodeURIComponent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) for your values to make them safe to pass. If you want to stay in the same tab, you could try [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

For example,

```
function addFrame(fid){  
  var xfra= encodeURIComponent("x"+fid);  
  var nfr= encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(xfra).value);  
  var nwo= encodeURIComponent(fid);  
  var link= "http://127.0.0.1/nims/index.php/jpbgr/frame/18?xid=18menu=new&order="+nwo+"&frame="+nfr;  
  var Util= window.location(link);   
}
```

The above will stop running the current page and open the new page in the tab your code was running in. If you want to populate an `iframe`, you should use the `contentWindow` property of the iframe instead of the `window` your code is in. Take a look at [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp) for more details on the `iframe`.